# Titanium Appcelerator Video Player Back Button on Android

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, video-player

I am new to Titanium App Development. I am making a title list of videos using a ListView. When I click on an item, the specific video plays fine. However when I press the back button in Android, the application exits instead of going back to the previous list of videos. I have tried *android:back* and *androidback* event of the window but still the same. How should I fix this??? By the way I am using the Alloy Framework in Titanium

**index.js**

```
videos.fetch({query: 'select * from '+ videos.config.adapter.collection_name + ' where video_id = '+ vid_id});
    var args;
    for (var vd=0 ; vd < videos.length; vd++){
        var e = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(videos.at(vd)));
        args = {
            parent_id : lsn_sub,
            video_data : e.video_data
        };

    console.log(args.video_data);
    var mediaview = Alloy.createController("media", args).getView();
    mediaview.open();
```

**media.js**

```
var parent_view = args.parent_id;
var vid_media = args.video_data;

    console.log("parent source: "+parent_view);
console.log($.vid_media.url);

    $.vid_media.url = vid_media ;

$.media.addEventListener('androidback', function(e){


    alert("android back");


});
```

**views/media.xml**

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
        <VideoPlayer id="vid_media" ns="Ti.Media" ></VideoPlayer>
</Window>
```

The back button exits the application, not going back to previous screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the great help @suraj and @victor, but I figured it out already.

The reason for it to be not working is because I was testing it only in the simulator, not on a real device. When I run it on the real device, the 'back button' of the android actually works fine. It stops my video and goes back to the previous screen.

We should really **test on a real device** rather than relying on a simulator. Have a great day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the model property of your **second window** true.

```
<SecondWindow class="container" modal="true"></SecondWindow>
```

Also set modal and exitOnClose true on your first window if you want to close the app when user press android back on your first screen.

```
<FirstWindow class="container" modal="true" exitOnClose></FirstWindow >
```

there is no to add android:back event for it.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution
is to cancel the [bubbling effect](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Event_Handling) of the `androidback` event,

```
$.media.addEventListener('androidback', function(e) {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    [...Your logic here...]
}
```